# Sinon spy on inherited function

Tags: javascript, sinon

How do I spy on an inherited function with sinon?

If I have -

```
    class Parent{
        constructor(){}
        foo(){
            //do foo
        }
    }

    class Child extend Parent{
        constructor(){
            super();
        }
    }

    const childSpy = sinon.spy(Child.prototype, 'foo')
    const parentSpy = sinon.spy(Parent.prototype, 'foo')


    new Child().foo();

    expect(childSpy).to.have.been.called; //false
    expect(parentSpy).to.have.been.called; //true
```

What am I doing wrong?

The above example is a simplified version of my code, in the actual code I do not have access to instances of either the `Child` or `Parent` classes

Answer (score 1):

So, I tried this and received different results than what you listed. In my case, the childSpy *is* being called, and the parentSpy is not, which-- given how sinon works-- is what I would expect. So I'll assume you go them mixed up in your post and proceed from there.

What's going on here is kind of subtle and hinges a bit on knowledge of what sinon actually does when it creates a spy in place on an object.

When this line is executed:

```
const childSpy = sinon.spy(Child.prototype, 'foo')
```

Sinon first accesses a property on `Child.prototype` called `foo.` This property does not actually exist on `Child.prototype`, so JavaScript steps up the prototype chain to `Parent.prototype,` where it *does* find such a property.

So, sinon obtains a reference to the original function stored `Parent.prototype.foo`. It wraps this function in a spy, then assigns it to `Child.prototype` as `Child.prototype.foo`.

The weirdness here is that `Child.prototype` did not have its own reference to the original `foo` function before, but now it does, and *that* is what will now be invoked when you call `foo` on an instance of `Child`.

When *this* line is executed:

const parentSpy = sinon.spy(Parent.prototype, 'foo')

Sinon accesses the function at `Parent.prototype.foo`, wraps it in a spy, and assigns the spy over it. This may seem like it should affect the function wrapped by the spy at `Child.prototype.foo`, but it doesn't. The spy located there is still wrapping the *original* `Parent.prototype.foo`.

It may occur to you to flip the order of your spy creation statements to try to get around this, but you'll find that sinon doesn't allow it. You can't wrap an already-mapped method. I.e if something is already a spy, attempting to use sinon to 'spy on the spy' will throw. There is good reason for this, though I'm sure it seems frustrating in this case.

It seems odd that you don't have access to instances of your classes, but if you really must do thing this way, one way around this problem would be to give the Child class its own `foo` method. All it needs to do is invoke the same method with the same signature on super:

```
class Parent{
    constructor(){}
    foo(){
        //do foo
    }
}

class Child extend Parent{
    constructor(){
        super();
    }

    foo(...args){
        return super.foo(...args)
    }
}

const childSpy = sinon.spy(Child.prototype, 'foo')
const parentSpy = sinon.spy(Parent.prototype, 'foo')


new Child().foo();

expect(childSpy).to.have.been.called;
expect(parentSpy).to.have.been.called;
```

Doing this will make your childSpy wrap `Child.prototype.foo`, which will invoke whatever the value of `Parent.prototype.foo` happens to be at the time it is called.

Answer (score 0):

You better try to spy on concrete object and no to the classes. 
e.g.

```
const expect = require('chai').expect;
const sinon = require('sinon');


describe('Some', () => {
  it('one', () => {
    class Parent {
      constructor() { }
      foo() {
        //do foo
      }
    }

    class Child extends Parent{
      constructor() {
        super();
      }
    }

    const child = new Child();
    const childSpy = sinon.spy(child, 'foo');

    child.foo();

    expect(childSpy.called).to.be.true; //true    

  });
});
```

Hope this help.

Comment: Thanks for input.  Unfortunately I don't have access to the instance, my example in the question is a simplified version to conceptually show my scenario.